# Symfony2 validation.yml for value of Array field type

Tags: validation, symfony

For each user I have name, surname and phone numbers. I need to validate these fields in my validation.yml to check if they are not empty. For name and surname validation I have this and it is working very well:

```
RFQ\IronilBundle\Entity\User:
properties:
    name:
        - NotBlank: { groups: [not_empty] }
    surname:
        - NotBlank: { groups: [not_empty] }
```

Problem is there that I can't to find any example in documentation how to validate phone field, because each user can have more than one phone number. My entity for phone is:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="array", nullable=true)
 * @Assert\NotNull()
 */
protected $phone;
```

and upon registering I insert in database empty array value (I need this to show empty phone field in my edit action):

```
public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->phone = array('');
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: I think the All validator do this job for you. [Theck the doc](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/reference/constraints/All.html)

Comment: You could always use a `Callback` validator that would call an entity method that does the checks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an `All` validation type that will iterate over `arrays` and `Traversable` objects and apply constraints to them. So for example, if you want to make sure each phone element is max 10 characters, you could do the following:

```
RFQ\IronilBundle\Entity\User:
properties:
    name:
        - NotBlank: { groups: [not_empty] }
    surname:
        - NotBlank: { groups: [not_empty] }
    phone:
        - All:
            - NotBlank:  ~
            - Length:
                max: 10
```

The [reference documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/All.html).

Comment: Thank you for answer! But I need to assign a group to this validation too. Maybe you know how I can do that?

Comment: `- All: { groups: [not_empty] }` throws me syntax error, but `- NotBlank: { groups: [not_empty] }` just doesn't work.

Comment: I think I remember having this conversation with someone else too. What was the error, that the `All` constraint doesn't support `groups`?

Comment: `Unable to parse at line 9 (near " - NotBlank: ~").`

Comment: Ah invalid yml syntax. So add `- groups: [not_empty]` as an element of `All` like the other properties (so just above `- NotBlank: ~`).

Comment: `Attempted to load class "groups" from namespace "Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints" in C:\wamp\www\rfqgroup.local\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Validator\Mapping\Loader\AbstractLoader.php line 64. Do you need to "use" it from another namespace?`

Comment: In official documentation are a lot of these examples `- NotBlank: { groups: [not_empty] }`, but they just don't work.

Comment: That's Symfony documentation sadly - far from perfect in describing component configurations. I think this problem occurs because the ALL constraint doesn't support a groups property and that may be by design, though I've never had to cross this bridge myself so I don't know why off hand. It will require a creative solution.